# How would you use anchor points in a div when using the flexcroll plugin?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a custom scrollbar on my main div which has buttons to go to certain parts of the div, however anchor points don't seem to work when using the flexcroll plugin (I know i'm doing anchor points correctly because when I disable flexcroll on that div they work fine)

Is their any method I could use to set up the anchor points?

EDIT FOUND SOLUTION: On the buttons I want to click to go to the specific place in the document I can put onclick="Wrapper.fleXcroll.setScrollPos(false,0);"

Answer (score 0):

I've used this function in the past. FYI, I don't know anything about flexcroll, so this is not tested with that:

```
var isInt = function(val) {
    return (parseInt(val, 10) == val);
};

var scrollTo = function(node) {
    var pNode = node.parentNode;
    var offset = node.offsetTop - pNode.offsetTop;
    var pHeight = pNode.clientHeight;
    var height = node.clientHeight;
    var scrollOffset = pNode.scrollTop;
    var buffer = 10;
    var scroll = null;

    if (scrollOffset > offset) {
        scroll = offset - buffer;
    } else if (pHeight + scrollOffset < offset + height + buffer) {
        scroll = offset + height + buffer - pHeight;
    }

    if (isInt(scroll)) {
        pNode.scrollTop = scroll;
    }
};
```

This is the pure JS version. ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/FMFug/1/))

Here is an example of a jQuery version, which animates the scroll event: [jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/7B3Jc/1/)